# How to know if an user stay in the page using beforeunload in Angular?

Tags: angular, decorator, preventdefault, onbeforeunload

I'm using a Dropzone to upload files to my web. I want to cancel the current uploading files and then delete the uploaded files in my storage. While files are uploading, if an user leaves site a default modal appear and he decides if stay or leaves.

This default modal in Chrome:

[image: Leave site modal]

My current code works when the user finally decides to leave site, but if the decide to stay, the code also runs.

I'm looking for a function or something that let me know if user stays of leaves the site for take a decision or another. In other words, I want to know which button the user clicks and where that information is stored.

Im using a HostListener decorator with a beforunload event:

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onWindowClose(event: any): void {
   // Some code
   event.preventDefault();
   event.returnValue = false;
   }
```

The code in the HostListener are executed whenever the user stays or leaves the site.